# Implement items list with multiple selection

Tags: xaml, user-interface, windows-phone-8, multipleselection

In my WP8 application I would like to implement a functionality that is very similar to what is present in standard mail app - an ability for user to select multiple items from list. I've provided some screenshots to illustrate this behavior:

Normal state:
[image: Normal state]

User taps item's left corner and it becomes blue:
[image: User taps item's left corner and it becomes blue]

Item is selected
[image: Item is selected]

My question is if this multiple selection ability is a standard option for some container control or if I should do some custom programming to achieve this? In the latter case, what's the best approach you'd take to implement this, please share your thoughts.

Comment: Anton, I exactly have the same requirement as yours where I need to perform show hide animation over the checkbox in the given listview. Pl share if you have figured out a solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For WP8 Multi-Selection you'll need to use the [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com)'s LongListMultiSelector.

You can find code samples on how to use LongListMultiSelector [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336298) (and [here](http://phone.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/80797#1336297) for the code behind). Here are the relevant XAML code snippets:

```xml
    <phone:PivotItem x:Name="BuddiesPivotItem" Header="Std longlistmultiselector">
        <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="buddies" Background="Transparent"
                Margin="0,-8,0,0"
                ItemsSource="{StaticResource buddies}"
                LayoutMode="List"
                IsGroupingEnabled="True"
                HideEmptyGroups="True"
                JumpListStyle="{StaticResource BuddiesJumpListStyle}"
                GroupHeaderTemplate="{StaticResource BuddiesGroupHeaderTemplate}"
                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource BuddiesItemTemplate}"
    />
    </phone:PivotItem>

    <phone:PivotItem x:Name="GridModeItem" Header="Grid mode">
        <toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="GridSelector"
               ItemsSource="{StaticResource PicturesAlbum}"
               IsGroupingEnabled="False"
               GridCellSize="210,180"
               LayoutMode="Grid"
               HideEmptyGroups="True"
               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PictureItemTemplate}"
               IsSelectionEnabledChanged="OnGridSelectorIsSelectionEnabledChanged"
               SelectionChanged="OnGridSelectorSelectionChanged"
        />
    </phone:PivotItem>
```

When you run these code snippet you can see the following:

[image: LongListMutliSelector print screen]

You can read more about the Windows Phone 8 Toolkit [here](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2012/11/20/windows-phone-toolkit-overview.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

the LonglistmultiSelector is missing in my toolkit..

if i run the following code:

```
<toolkit:LongListMultiSelector x:Name="EmailList" 
                                                Margin="0,14,-12,0"
                                                ItemsSource="{StaticResource EmailCollection}"
                                                LayoutMode="List"
                                                SelectionChanged="OnEmailListSelectionChanged"
                                                          IsSelectionEnabledChanged="OnEmailListIsSelectionEnabledChanged"
                                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource EmailItemTemplate}"
                                                ItemInfoTemplate="{StaticResource EmailItemInfoTemplate}"
            />
```

if get the Error:
Error   1   The name "LongListMultiSelector" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit".

Comment: Maybe you have to add the following line among the other xmlns declarations at the top of MainPage.xaml: 
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"