# Trouble with multiple selection of a list box in wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm using ListBox to list a group of items and i want the user to select multiple items from the list. I tried it with the following code,

```
<ListBox x:Name="List" SelectionMode="Multiple" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="559" Margin="14,1,-1,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="443" SelectionChanged="List_SelectionChanged_1">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="420" Height="60">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="tbName" Width="318" Foreground="{Binding color}" Height="35" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="-350,13,69,12" />
                        <Canvas x:Name="ContentPanelCanvas" Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent"  Margin="0,0,12,0">
                            <Line X1="0" Y1="00" X2="420" Y2="0" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="0.3"/>
                        </Canvas>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

But still i didn't get a checkbox to select multiple items.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think it will be better if you use `LongListMultiSelector` from [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/)
You can find code samples [here.](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-toolkit-multiselectlist-in-depth--part1-key-concepts-and-api) Also take a look of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14129337/implement-items-list-with-multiple-selection).